# FluentNHibernate - Overriding an IIdConvention with different Id generator and type yields exception

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

if i have a convention for mapping ids that is how i generally map that uses the hilo generatior on an int Id property with an int Id column:

```
public class IdConvention : IIdConvention
{
    private const int HiLoRange = short.MaxValue;

    public void Apply(IIdentityInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Column(instance.EntityType.Name + "Id");
        instance.GeneratedBy.HiLo(HiLoRange.ToString());
    }
}
```

but i have a class i want to map differently, with an assigned string as the Id instead, i use an override:

```
public class SomeClassMapping : IAutoMappingOverride<SomeClass>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<SomeClass> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Id(instance => instance.StringProperty).GeneratedBy.Assigned().Column("StringProperty");
    }
}
```

this worked in older versions of FluentNHibernate/NHibernate, but when i update to 1.3.0.733/3.3.2.4000, i now fall victim to an unhandled exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Identity type must be integral (int, long, uint, ulong)

this only happens if i'm trying to use a string (or some other non-integral property as the Id) should i expect that i'm no longer able to override a mapping and give a different generator and type, or is there something i can do differently to make the override hide that i want to do hilo in the general case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks like the order of execution changed. an easy fix would be to

```
public void Apply(IIdentityInstance instance)
{
    if (instance.Type == typeof(int))
    {
        instance.Column(instance.EntityType.Name + "Id");
        instance.GeneratedBy.HiLo(HiLoRange.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for that.  i had come up with that as a workaround after posting the question as well (although might want to include long, uint, ulong for a more general solution).  i was hoping i just was doing something wrong and that overriding would actually still override the attempt to use hilo.

Comment: I think that checking (instance.Generator.EntityType == null) is more reliable because it would pass only if the GeneratedBy wasn't set by the mapping.

Comment: FluentNHibernate uses layered configurations so it will use "defined in mappings" ?? "convention" ?? "default" where "??" means "if present"